# Famo.us Scrollview height

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I am trying to add a image below a scrollview using the famous sequentialLayout and im having a problem with the scrollview's height.

This is how i create my scrollview.

```
var scrollview = new Scrollview({       
    direction: Utility.Direction.X,
    options: {
        size: [300, 300]
    },        
    paginated: true
});
```

When i add surfaces to the scrollview with 250 height, the scrollview's parent DOM container (famous-group) containing these surfaces has a width and height of 0.

When adding this scrollview within a sequentialLayout as the first item, the second item or surface with a height is displayed on top of this scrollview since it has no height.

Any ideas how to fix this using Famo.us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't set size like that - use a modifier for this.

This will be the render tree

```
MainContext
   SequentialLayout
      Modifier(size)
          ScrollView
      Modifier(size)
          Image
```

Code snippet:

```
// Create components
var scrollview = new ScrollView();
var image = new ImageSurface({
    content: 'content/images/famous_symbol_transparent.png'
});

// Create Size Modifiers
var scrollModifier = new StateModifier({ size: [200,200]});
var imageModifier = new StateModifier({ size: [200,200]});

// Wrap the Modifier in a RenderNode, so we can add the surface
// (you can't add surfaces directly to a modifier)
var scrollNode = new RenderNode(scrollModifier)
scrollNode.add(scrollview);

var imageNode = new RenderNode(imageModifier);
imageNode.add(image);

// Create a SequentialLayout
var sequence = new SequentialLayout();
sequence.sequenceFrom([scrollNode,imageNode]);
```

And here is an [example gist](https://gist.github.com/markmarijnissen/10644653) (copy-paste the `main.js` after running the `yo famous` generator)

Comment: You are correct, found this out myself aswel but your code is better written and documented :-) Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! It is even more fun is you use "scrollModifier.sizeFrom" to dynamically set size to 50% of your screenheight!