# Famous: Swipe items within a Scrollview

Tags: famo.us

I'm looking to implement similar functionality to Mailbox (http://www.mailboxapp.com/) where you can swipe an individual item within a list in order to action it, using Famous (http://famo.us).

I tried to add the 'Draggable' modifier to each list item, however it seems that you can't add modifiers to surfaces that are part of a Scrollview.

Anyone (from Famous or otherwise) know how I might do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out. In order to modifiers to surfaces inside a scrollview, they need to be wrapped in a RenderNode.

```
var Engine     = require("famous/core/Engine");
var Surface    = require("famous/core/Surface");
var Scrollview = require("famous/views/Scrollview");
var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
var Draggable = require('famous/modifiers/Draggable');

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

var scrollview = new Scrollview();
var surfaces = [];

scrollview.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

for (var i = 0, temp; i < 40; i++) {

    draggable = new Draggable( {
        xRange: [-220, 220],
        yRange: [0, 0],
    });

    item = new Surface({
         content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
         size: [undefined, 200],
         properties: {
             backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
             lineHeight: "200px",
             textAlign: "center"
         }
    });

    node = new RenderNode(draggable)
    node.add(item);

    item.pipe(draggable);
    item.pipe(scrollview);
    surfaces.push(node);

}

mainContext.add(scrollview);
```

via @ (markmarijnissen) [Famo.us Scrollview height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057349/famo-us-scrollview-height))

Comment: Ah. This helps. I was just trying to allow dragging of a random Surface and shoving it in a RenderNode fixed the problem. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Just getting started with famo.us, could you tell me what item.pipe() is doing. Thanks.

Comment: @nimgrg in a nutshell, you use item.pipe() to pass events between parent and children elements. so if someone clicks on the parent element, the child element will also receive the click event

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:** In a `Scrollview`, the `sequenceFrom` method creates a `ViewSequence` from the array. As long as the items being added can return a `getSize()`, the rendering will work correctly. The `RenderNode` meets this criteria. You can also create a custom `View` because it extends `RenderNode` also.

Below is a code snippet that uses a custom View that allows the surface to drag and shows a response to the drag direction based on the final position criteria.

```js
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
  var Scrollview = require("famous/views/Scrollview");
  var DragView = require('DragView');

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

  var scrollview = new Scrollview();
  var views = [];

  scrollview.sequenceFrom(views);

  for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

    var view = new DragView({
      size: [undefined, 200],
      content: "Surface: " + (i + 1),
      backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 20) + ", 100%, 70%)"
    });

    view._eventOutput.pipe(scrollview);
    views.push(view);

  }

  mainContext.add(scrollview);
});

// Custom Drag View Item
define('DragView', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Surface = require("famous/core/Surface");
  var Scrollview = require("famous/views/Scrollview");
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var View = require('famous/core/View');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var Draggable = require('famous/modifiers/Draggable');
  var TransitionableTransform = require('famous/transitions/TransitionableTransform');
  var RenderController = require('famous/views/RenderController');

  function _updatingDrag(e) {
    var pos = e.position;
    this.surface.setContent('Draggable Position is ' + pos);
  }

  function _endDrag(e) {
    var pos = e.position;
    this.surface.setContent('Draggable End Position is ' + pos);
    this.draggable.setPosition([0, 0], {
      duration: 300
    }, function() {
      this.renderer.hide();
    }.bind(this));

    if (pos[0] > 200) {
      console.log('showing OK');
      this.renderer.show(this.ok);
    }

    if (pos[0] < -200) {
      console.log('showing Not OK');
      this.renderer.show(this.not);
    }
  }

  function DragView() {
    View.apply(this, arguments);

    var draggable = new Draggable({
      xRange: [-220, 220],
      yRange: [0, 0],
    });

    var item = new Surface({
      content: this.options.content,
      size: [undefined, 200],
      properties: {
        backgroundColor: this.options.backgroundColor,
        lineHeight: "200px",
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    });

    var okItem = new Surface({
      content: String.fromCharCode(10004),
      size: [220, 200],
      properties: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        lineHeight: "200px",
        fontSize: "100px",
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    });
    var notOkItem = new Surface({
      content: String.fromCharCode(10006),
      size: [220, 200],
      properties: {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        lineHeight: "200px",
        fontSize: "100px",
        textAlign: "center"
      }
    });

    var renderer = new RenderController();

    draggable.subscribe(item);

    draggable.on('update', _updatingDrag.bind({
      surface: item
    }));

    draggable.on('end', _endDrag.bind({
      surface: item,
      draggable: draggable,
      renderer: renderer,
      ok: okItem,
      not: notOkItem
    }));

    item.pipe(this._eventOutput);
    
    this.add(draggable).add(item)
    this.add(renderer);
  }

  DragView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
  DragView.prototype.constructor = DragView;


  module.exports = DragView;
});

// Start Main App
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```